# Has it been officially confirmed that Stan Lee was talking to Watchers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, stan-lee, watcher

In *Marvel's Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* movie, Stan Lee was seen talking to some bald blue aliens. Internet is on fire over this. Everyone is saying that Stan Lee's cameos in other MCU movies isn't a coincidence and he is actually an informant of Watchers.

Although it looks a great theory, I am not buying it. I mean, seriously? From when do Watchers need an informant? I haven't encountered them in comics so far, but when Galactus was about to attack Silver Surfer's original planet in cartoon, a Watcher appeared in the sky to warn them. Also, it should be obvious by the name that they can watch everything. If not, one Google search is enough.

On the other hand, it is possible that MCU version of Watchers can't see everything by themselves and they indeed need an informant. Has it been officially confirmed or referenced or shown in the canon that those blue bald aliens were Watchers? They looked more like Oa's guardians than Watchers.

Comment: The end of the movie explicitly credits Stan Lee as 'Watcher informant'. The bald aliens he's speaking to also are visually identical to the Watchers of the comics.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes.

It wasn't hard to figure out to begin with; this is what a Watcher looks like:

[image]

In addition, Lee was credited in the movie as "Watcher informant", and the only thing we see him doing in the film is relaying information to 3 aliens, who by deduction must be Watchers.

Finally, James Gunn (the director) [has admitted](http://movieweb.com/stan-lee-marvel-movie-cameos-character-watchers-informant/) that the inclusion of The Watchers are partly an homage to Lee himself, who came up with the idea for the characters and was initially ridiculed for it:

> "When he first brought up the Watchers in the '60s, the other writers were making fun of him and thought they were a stupid idea. He was like, 'I like them,' and he put them in. So Stan feels particularly redeemed.

---

One word of caution: *a whole ton* of articles that came out in during the early release period claims that Lee was playing *a Watcher*, possibly even Uatu himself. As far as we know, that's entirely false. The Watchers are clearly separate entities, that look nothing like Lee, and have no problem breathing on the moon with a human space suit. Lee is playing *a person* who happens to be working for the Watchers.

Comment: In his Cameos, Stan Lee barely watches anything to inform that to Watchers. In Doctor Strange for example, he was reading book unaware about the ongoing fight. Even if he was pretending to read, I doubt normal humans could watch such magical fights. Unless, he is not a human....

Comment: Marvel Comics in the '60s were very ground-based and realistic, so it makes sense that the other writers thought the Watchers were dumb. /s

Comment: The cameo confirms a fan theory that Stan has been playing the SAME CHARACTER in all the Marvel movies, ending up in bizarre situations each time. "That time I was a fedex delivery guy" refers to his appearance in Civil War.

Comment: well, that's debatable. Civil War doesn't happen in-universe for 2 more years. he could have been a fedex guy some other time though.

Comment: @KutuluMike or we could use this as evidence for Stan travelling through time as well.

Comment: @ILoveYou They leave him there without giving him a ride home. Just because he's an informant doesn't mean he's good/competent at informing them of relevant stuff.

Comment: I saw [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqwhxy6Bwrs) there may be more quotes from the director confirming that Lee is a Watcher.

Comment: @Skooba I watched the video; I'm 99% sure he's talking about the James Gunn quote I included in my answer [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72766/did-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-confirm-that-marvel-now-has-the-rights-to-fant/72767#72767), which doesn't confirm anything other than Lee is the same character in every movie and he's working with the Watchers. He may be a Watcher or he may just be a human agent of theirs, we don't know yet.